# Prolog: get vs. at_end_of_stream for checking end of file

Tags: file, prolog, eof

I am reading a file using prolog and was wondering about the difference of saying:

```
processRead(Stream, ...) :- at_end_of_stream(Stream), !.
```

and:

```
processRead(Stream, ...) :- get(Stream, Ch), Ch is -1, !.
```

Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first! Follow [@mat's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812888/4609915)!

**If** you need to chose, 
**always prefer using `at_end_of_stream/1`** over `get/2`!

- `get/2` is *deprecated*. If you have decade-old legacy code, migrate it.

  If your code is new, don't ever use it. Never. Not even once.
- `at_end_of_stream/1` is defined by the [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog) standard.
- Virtually **every modern Prolog processor supports `at_end_of_stream/1`**—including (but not limited to)
  [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec126), [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dat_005fend_005fof_005fstream.html), [SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=at_end_of_stream/1), [B-Prolog](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/download/manual.pdf), and [Eclipse CLP](http://www.webmail.eclipseclp.org/doc_5_9/bips/lib/iso/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for asking... As a rule of thumb, do not use *[deprecated]* Prolog predicates, ever!

Answer (score 3):

Both are extremely low-level ways to access file content, and you should instead use better methods altogether.

In SWI-Prolog, the most elegant solution is to:

1. Write a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) that describes the content.
2. Use Ulrich Neumerkel's [library(pio)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio) and its `phrase_from_file/2` to apply the DCG to a file.

This has several advantages: You can actually test the DCG interactively, not needing a file at all. The method is pure and can be applied in several directions. etc. etc.

Comment: I know but I want to do it the way described above.

Comment: That's nice, and I want to advertise how you should do it instead, if not for your own benefit, then at least for that of other readers.

Answer (score 1):

(coming late to the party)
I would strongly suggest that you *never* use `at_end_of_stream/1`. Instead I recommend your first approach, i.e. attempt to read (using something standard, like `get_code/2`, of course) and then check whether you got an end-of-file indicator.

1. Presumably, if the stream is not at its end, you will read a character anyway, so you may just as well read it immediately and handle the (rare) EOF as part of your ordinary processing of characters.
2. `at_end_of_stream/1` is broken by design, since it is blocking (and may write a prompt if reading from the terminal). So, for many kinds of streams it is not really possible to determine whether the stream is at its end until it has been closed by the other side, which may never happen. For this reason, in SICStus Prolog, `at_end_of_stream/1` will fail instead of blocking, so using `at_end_of_stream/1` will not give the result that you expect.

So, always attempting to read is maximally portable, most likely faster, and will not do strange things on some streams.

Comment: `iso_at_end_of_stream(S) :- peek_code(S, _).` but only for text-streams.